# replace characters in a text file - logic error?

Tags: c, argv

user types $./replace i xy data.txt
**data.txt** contains the words "this is a test file, test file only". Therefore, all i's will be replaced with xy, i.e. thxys xys a test fxyle, test fxyle only

I think I am quite close. However, instead of replacing i with xy, my code just replaces i with x. I think the error is at line 38 strcpy.
However, is the logic correct from line 30 to 40? I am trying to say....

For each element in the first buffer(buf)
    copy buf element into another buffer (temp) one character at a time
    if buf element == 'i'
          copy 'xy' to 'i'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 


#define BUFFERSIZE 4096

/*replace i xy data.txt */

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{

    int in_fd, out_fd, n_chars, BufElement,j,x;
    ssize_t nread,nwrite;
    off_t newpos;
    char buf[BUFFERSIZE],temp[300];


        /*Open file containing original data*/
        if ( (in_fd=open(av[3], O_RDWR)) == -1 )
        {
            printf("Cannot open %s\n", av[3]);
            exit(1);
        }


        /*Read characters from file to buffer*/
        while ( (nread = read(in_fd , buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0 )
        {
            for (BufElement=0;BufElement < nread;BufElement++)
            {
                for (j=0; j < strlen(av[1]); j++)
                {
                    temp[BufElement] = buf[BufElement];
                    if (buf[BufElement] == av[1][j])
                        strncpy(temp+BufElement,av[2],strlen(av[2])); /*ERROR*/

                }

            }
        }

        printf("%s\n",buf);
        printf("%s\n",temp);

            newpos = lseek(in_fd, 0, SEEK_SET); 

            nwrite = write(in_fd,temp,36); 

            close(in_fd);
        }

}
```

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Have you looked at `sed` and the use of a temporary file?

Comment: yes but i would like to write my own command

Comment: You can put the line `temp[BufElement] = buf[BufElement];` outside the innermost loop.

Comment: your temp[300]; my be too small if i call ./replace x yyyyyy...400times..yyyy data.txt

Answer (score 3):

you only have one increment of `BufElement`, but because your dest-buffer may be getting larger or smaller than the input, you should have two counters/pointers; one for the next place to write into your dest-buffer, and one which resembles the input-buffer.

**EDIT**: pseudo code:

```
while src[i]
  if match
    dest[j] = replacement
    j += strlen(replacement)
    i += 1
  else
    dest[j] = src[i];
    i += 1
    j += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `i` was replaced by `xy`, but then `y` gets replaced by the letter in your first `buf`(buf) by `temp[BufElement] = buf[BufElement]`.

Like Peter Miehle said, you need a counter to mark the shift every time you do the replacement:

```
strncpy(temp+BufElement,av[2],strlen(av[2]))
```

Comment: Something like this ?

     while ( (nread = read(in_fd , buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0 )
        {
            for (BufElement=0;BufElement < nread;BufElement++)
            {
                for (j=0; j < strlen(av[1]); j++)
                {
                    temp[x] = buf[BufElement];
                    if (buf[BufElement] == av[1][j]){
                        strncpy(temp+x,av[2],strlen(av[2])); 
   x = BufElement + 1;
         }
                                 
                }
                     
            }
        }